# wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele)) is not working

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

When I click one submit button, One pop up (Modal) window get open.

Here I have to click on any one of the buttons among the list of the button. So after clicking on the submit button, I am using wait function to wait till the element to be clickable.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(oBrowser, stimeout);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
```

But the program was stuck here. It will not click on any button.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: please share your exception as well, please check answer as well.

Comment: What happens when you get rid of the wait and you put a sleep in front of trying to click it with enough time to make sure it appears? My guess is you'll get some exception, which is why `elementToBeClickable` isn't returning. You're probably waiting for the wrong element, and trying to click the wrong element as well. That's the best guess I can offer since there is no `html` or **selector** in the question. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In questions , There is one new window get opened. As per selenium documentations, script can not work with two window simultaneously.

So solution is script need to move to that screen/window/frame.

### **As per my knowledge, there are two possibilities :**

***1. Browser Window :***

- First switch to window and make script

  ```
     // Switch to new window opened
      for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
      driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
      if(driver.getTitle().equals("your title")){
         // your code
         wait = new WebDriverWait(oBrowser, stimeout);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
       }
      }
  ```

***2. Frame :***

- First switch to frame and do script actions (Note : you would see `<iframe>` tag in HTML page )

  By Index : `driver.switchTo().frame(0);`

  By Name  : `driver.switchTo().frame("name of the iframe element");`

  By ID    : `driver.switchTo().frame("id of the iframe element");`

[Reference](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)

---

Note : May be that modal window is integrated with existing window. Please check your page loaded properly or not.